# Why is the size of the UIImage 3xtimes larger than the real size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I use some pretty large images in my app. Their resolution is large so it'll look nice on iphone 6+. The size of images is about 3.5MB.

When I runn the app on iphone and load the images in cell with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]`; If I scroll through all 10 cells, it fill memory up to 100MB. 
I look in the Instruments and it shows me that each image is 9MB large. Is this normal?

Here is my code of UICollectionViewCell, and I must tell you that the cells are loading fine, one at the time, so there is nothing wrong with cells.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WallpaperCell *cell = (WallpaperCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"wallpaperCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    NSString *imageName = [self.wallpapers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [cell setWallpaperImage:image];
    [cell setWallpaperName:imageName];
    NSLog(@"cell:%@",cell);
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw the image to the screen the UIImage needs to be a bitmap which has no compression. Your png is in a compressed format so is much smaller than the bitmap representation.